# How to delete similar key in different object of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So I have this array of an object having multiples objects, I want to delete the date keys from the objects i.e createdDate and modifiedDate

I've tried using a for loop and use delete function but nothing happens.

```
 var data = matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket;
 matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket.forEach(element => {
    if (matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket.hasOwnProperty("createdDate")) {
                  delete ["createdDate"];
    }
 });
 console.table(data);

 var matchScoreData = {
    "tbl_FallOfWicket": [
                {
                  "pk_fallWicketID": 119,
                  "fk_matchID": 133137,
                  "fk_teamID": 141065,
                  "fk_dismissTypeID": 3,
                  "fk_dismissPlayerID": 969155,
                  "run": 40,
                  "wicket": 1,
                  "over": "5.1",
                  "inning": 1,
                  "createdDate": "2018-08-18T03:06:12+0000",
                  "modifiedDate": "",
                },
                {
                  "pk_fallWicketID": 120,
                  "fk_matchID": 133137,
                  "fk_teamID": 141065,
                  "fk_dismissTypeID": 1,
                  "fk_dismissPlayerID": 939721,
                  "run": 88,
                  "wicket": 2,
                  "over": "9.5",
                  "createdDate": "2018-08-18T03:06:12+0000",
                  "modifiedDate": "",
                  "inning": 1
       }
    ]};
```

I'm getting same values in output

Comment: Issue is here: `delete["createdDate"];` You are trying to delete but from where? You are missing that part

Comment: @Rajesh I guess here delete matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket.["createdDate"];

Comment: @codenoobie **No**, actually it should be `delete element["createdDate"]` to refer to the right iterated `element`, check [my **answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57091184/3669624) below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be `delete element.createDate` (same for any other property)

```js
var matchScoreData = {

  "tbl_FallOfWicket": [{
      "pk_fallWicketID": 119,
      "fk_matchID": 133137,
      "fk_teamID": 141065,
      "fk_dismissTypeID": 3,
      "fk_dismissPlayerID": 969155,
      "run": 40,
      "wicket": 1,
      "over": "5.1",
      "inning": 1,
      "createdDate": "2018-08-18T03:06:12+0000",
      "modifiedDate": "",
    },
    {
      "pk_fallWicketID": 120,
      "fk_matchID": 133137,
      "fk_teamID": 141065,
      "fk_dismissTypeID": 1,
      "fk_dismissPlayerID": 939721,
      "run": 88,
      "wicket": 2,
      "over": "9.5",
      "createdDate": "2018-08-18T03:06:12+0000",
      "modifiedDate": "",
      "inning": 1
    }
  ]
};

var data = matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket;
matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket.forEach(element => {
  if (element.hasOwnProperty("createdDate")) {
    delete element.createdDate;
  }
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: how can someone downvote this answer? This works perfectly.

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma The answer was shorter originally. So I guess downvotes were for not providing a working example :)

Comment: Agree. My answer is also similar. Happy coding

Comment: also what if I want to print just those two keys and exclude everything else

Comment: Then you could better use `map` and create a new array containing new objects with only properties you need. `console.log(data.map(({prop1, prop2}) => ({prop1, prop2})))`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using `delete["createdDate"]`, it should be `delete element["createdDate"]` so it can delete the right property from the iterated `element`.

```
matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket.forEach(element => {
  if (element.hasOwnProperty("createdDate")) {
    delete element["createdDate"];
  }
});
```

**Note:**

Another bigger issue with your code is

```
if (matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket.hasOwnProperty("createdDate"))
```

`matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket` is an array and hence this condition will always return false. Due to this `delete['...']` is never executed.

You will have to check at individual object instead.

```
if (element.hasOwnProperty("createdDate"))
```

**Demo:**

```js
var matchScoreData = {
  "tbl_FallOfWicket": [{
      "pk_fallWicketID": 119,
      "fk_matchID": 133137,
      "fk_teamID": 141065,
      "fk_dismissTypeID": 3,
      "fk_dismissPlayerID": 969155,
      "run": 40,
      "wicket": 1,
      "over": "5.1",
      "inning": 1,
      "createdDate": "2018-08-18T03:06:12+0000",
      "modifiedDate": "",
    },
    {
      "pk_fallWicketID": 120,
      "fk_matchID": 133137,
      "fk_teamID": 141065,
      "fk_dismissTypeID": 1,
      "fk_dismissPlayerID": 939721,
      "run": 88,
      "wicket": 2,
      "over": "9.5",
      "createdDate": "2018-08-18T03:06:12+0000",
      "modifiedDate": "",
      "inning": 1
    }
  ]
};

var data = matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket;
matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket.forEach(element => {
  if (element.hasOwnProperty("createdDate")) {
    delete element["createdDate"];
  }
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: It seems OP wants to modify original data. Also this would still mutate original array items.

Comment: There is bigger problem here: `if(matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket.hasOwnProperty("createdDate"))`. You have addressed it in your code so it would be better if you highlight that as well

Comment: @Rajesh Well pointed out, yes it would be better as well. Thank you.

Comment: @cнŝdk I took the liberty to update your answer. If any of my edit is not required, please revert the changes

Comment: @Rajesh Absolutely no, you described facts better, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

following works, Here in your if condition you are referring the original object however you should be working on the current element, in your case you need to use
delete element["yourkey"].

Below is the JS which will work for you.

```
var data = matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket;
    matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket.forEach(element => {
      if (element.hasOwnProperty("createdDate")) {
        delete element["createdDate"];
      }
    });
    console.table(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
var matchScoreData = {
  tbl_FallOfWicket: [
    {
      pk_fallWicketID: 119,
      fk_matchID: 133137,
      fk_teamID: 141065,
      fk_dismissTypeID: 3,
      fk_dismissPlayerID: 969155,
      run: 40,
      wicket: 1,
      over: "5.1",
      inning: 1,
      createdDate: "2018-08-18T03:06:12+0000",
      modifiedDate: ""
    },
    {
      pk_fallWicketID: 120,
      fk_matchID: 133137,
      fk_teamID: 141065,
      fk_dismissTypeID: 1,
      fk_dismissPlayerID: 939721,
      run: 88,
      wicket: 2,
      over: "9.5",
      createdDate: "2018-08-18T03:06:12+0000",
      modifiedDate: "",
      inning: 1
    }
  ]
};

for(let i=0;i<matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket.length;i++){
    delete matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket[i].createdDate;
    delete matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket[i].modifiedDate;
}

console.log(matchScoreData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're assigning the output to a new variable anyway you could make use of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and some [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
var matchScoreData = {"tbl_FallOfWicket":[{"pk_fallWicketID":119,"fk_matchID":133137,"fk_teamID":141065,"fk_dismissTypeID":3,"fk_dismissPlayerID":969155,"run":40,"wicket":1,"over":"5.1","inning":1,"createdDate":"2018-08-18T03:06:12+0000","modifiedDate":""},{"pk_fallWicketID":120,"fk_matchID":133137,"fk_teamID":141065,"fk_dismissTypeID":1,"fk_dismissPlayerID":939721,"run":88,"wicket":2,"over":"9.5","createdDate":"2018-08-18T03:06:12+0000","modifiedDate":"","inning":1}]};

const data = matchScoreData.tbl_FallOfWicket.map(obj => {

  // pluck out the dates and assign the rest of the properties
  // to "rest", then simply return those properties
  const { createdDate, modifiedDate, ...rest } = obj;
  return rest;
});

console.log(data);
```